# Plotting the frequency associated with bigrams

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have frequency of each bigrams of a dataset.I need to sort it by descending order and visualise the top n bigrams.This is my frequency associated with each bigrams

```
{('best', 'price'): 95, ('price', 'range'): 190, ('range', 'got'): 5, ('got', 'diwali'): 2, ('diwali', 'sale'): 2, ('sale', 'simply'): 1, ('simply', 'amazed'): 1, ('amazed', 'performance'): 1, ('performance', 'camera'): 30, ('camera', 'clarity'): 35, ('clarity', 'device'): 1, ('device', 'speed'): 1, ('speed', 'looks'): 1, ('looks', 'display'): 1, ('display', 'everything'): 2, ('everything', 'nice'): 5, ('nice', 'heats'): 2, ('heats', 'lot'): 14, ('lot', 'u'): 2, ('u', 'using'): 3, ('using', 'months'): 20, ('months', 'no'): 10, ('no', 'problems'): 8, ('problems', 'whatsoever'): 1, ('whatsoever', 'great'): 1
```

Can anyone help me visualise these bigrams?

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? Please provide the relevant code as an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you need

```
import seaborn as sns
bg_dict = {('best', 'price'): 95, ('price', 'range'): 190, ('range', 'got'): 5, ('got', 'diwali'): 2, ('diwali', 'sale'): 2, ('sale', 'simply'): 1,
       ('simply', 'amazed'): 1, ('amazed', 'performance'): 1, ('performance', 'camera'): 30, ('camera', 'clarity'): 35, ('clarity', 'device'): 1,
       ('device', 'speed'): 1, ('speed', 'looks'): 1, ('looks', 'display'): 1, ('display', 'everything'): 2, ('everything', 'nice'): 5, ('nice', 'heats'): 2, ('heats', 'lot'): 14,
       ('lot', 'u'): 2, ('u', 'using'): 3, ('using', 'months'): 20, ('months', 'no'): 10, ('no', 'problems'): 8, ('problems', 'whatsoever'): 1, ('whatsoever', 'great'): 1}

bg_dict_sorted = sorted(bg_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
bg, counts = list(zip(*bg_dict_sorted))
bg_str = list(map(lambda x: '-'.join(x), bg))
sns.barplot(bg_str, counts)
```